# In C#, how do field initializers and object initializers interact?

Tags: c#, mono, initialization, unity-game-engine

I'm primarily a C++ developer, but recently I've been working on a project in C#. Today I encountered some behavior that was unexpected, at least to me, while using object initializers. I'm hoping someone here can explain what's going on.

Example A

```
public class Foo {
    public bool Bar = false;
}

PassInFoo( new Foo { Bar = true } );
```

Example B

```
public class Foo {
    public bool Bar = true;
}

PassInFoo( new Foo { Bar = false } );
```

Example A works as I'd expect. The object passed into PassInFoo has Bar set to true. However, in Example B, foo.Bar is set to true, despite being assigned false in the object initializer. What would be causing the object initializer in Example B to be seemingly ignored?

Comment: Nothing.  You aren't seeing what you think you're seeing.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, .Net 3.5, what version do you have and are you sure this is the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: Constructor will be run before object initializer and field initializer are part of constructor. See C# Specs: from 7.6.10 - 
Processing of an object creation expression that includes an object initializer or collection initializer consists of first processing the instance constructor and then processing the member or element initializations specified by the object initializer (§7.6.10.2) or collection initializer (§7.6.10.3).

Comment: It is working fine in .net 4.0 as well. Can you give more details and post the complete code?

Comment: @Scott - not to be unkind, but your comment is false. Several commenters (including me) have tried it and it compiles fine.

Comment: The code is actually part of a Unity3D project, which uses MonoDevelop to compile. I was assuming that Unity was using standard C#, but that may not be entirely correct. I couldn't repro it myself after trying the given code in Visual Studio. So either Unity is doing something odd, or the example code isn't representative of my actual code. I'll look into which is the case.

Comment: @Scott: Object initializers work perfectly well on fields, so long as you've got access to the field in question. See section 7.6.10.2 of the C# spec.

Comment: @Joel @Jon: Well, I guess I learned something today!  [deleting original comment as to not mislead others..]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to see what is happening is to break out your statement into its equivalent if done line-by-line.

Original:

```
PassInFoo( new Foo { Bar = false } );
```

Broken out:

```
var tmp = new Foo();    //Bar initialized to true
tmp.Bar = false;
PassInFoo( tmp );
```

Comment: Btw, I tested the above in .NET 3.5 and 4.0 and in both cases, Bar is in fact false inside of `PassInFoo`.

Comment: I just gave this a try in my Unity3D project and it worked correctly. Unity or MonoDevelop must be doing some 'optimization' of ignoring object initializer assignments if the assignments are of the type's default value (false for bool in my example code). I'll probably have to take this question to those communities for a more specific answer.

Comment: @nschrag - It would be highly disturbing to find out that one of those environments was messing with the evaluation order. Good luck!

Comment: Side note: If you are initializing an anonymous type, say like, `new { Bar = false }`, then there is no default constructor being called. Anonymous types simply don't have default empty constructors unless the anonymous type is `new { }`. Just saying, since both named type `new Foo { Bar = false }` and anonymous type `new { Bar = false }` look like using the same kind of object initializer.

Answer (score 5):

I confirm this ugly bug in Unity3d build of Mono (Mono 2.6.5, Unity3d 4.1.2f1, OSX).

It looks like it doesn't like to use the default value for the ValueType, so you can pass a `int != 0`, `(bool)true` etc just fine, but passing in the default value like `(int)0` or `(bool)false` ignores it's value.

Proof:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Foo1 {
    public bool Bar=false;
}

public class Foo2 {
    public bool Bar=true;
}

public class Foo1i {
    public int Bar=0;
}

public class Foo2i {
    public int Bar=42;
}

public class PropTest:MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        PassInFoo(new Foo1 {Bar=true}); // FOO1: True (OK)
        PassInFoo(new Foo2 {Bar=false});/// FOO2: True (FAIL!)
        PassInFoo(new Foo1i {Bar=42});  // FOO1i: 42 (OK)
        PassInFoo(new Foo2i {Bar=0});/// FOO2i: 42 (FAIL!)
        PassInFoo(new Foo2i {Bar=13});/// FOO2i: 13 (OK)
    }

    void PassInFoo(Foo1 f) {Debug.Log("FOO1: "+f.Bar);}

    void PassInFoo(Foo2 f) {Debug.Log("FOO2: "+f.Bar);}

    void PassInFoo(Foo1i f) {Debug.Log("FOO1i: "+f.Bar);}

    void PassInFoo(Foo2i f) {Debug.Log("FOO2i: "+f.Bar);}
}
```

On a non-unity3d OSX Mono 2.10.11 (mono-2-10/2baeee2 Wed Jan 16 16:40:16 EST 2013) the tests are running fine:

```
FOO1: True
FOO2: False
FOO1i: 42
FOO2i: 0
FOO2i: 13
```

EDIT: filled in a bug in unity3d's bugtracker: https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?548851_3gh8hi55oum1btda

Comment: Just checked on Unity 5 (editor only) - this bug still persists. Happy debuging.

Comment: Just got a message from Unity QA - they will fix this bug in an unspecified future release.

Comment: impressive stuff, @ChanibaL

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with Unity & Mono.

I got around it by initializing the fields in the constructor and then overwriting with the object initializers.

HOWEVER ! At first this didn't work either.  So I replaced the fields with properties with backing fields and it seemed to force expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PassInFoo( new Foo { Bar = false } );
    }
    public class Foo
    {
        public bool Bar = true;
    }

    public static void PassInFoo(Foo obj)

    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Bar.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine when verified with Framework 3.5 (false is displayed on the console window).